# Putting Scrollbar on Frame that is on Canvas

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

I am new to Python and Tkinter.

I am practicing on the use of Frames, Canvas, and Scrollbars and I got a problem:

I have a Canvas that acts as my Master and a Frame that is on the specific coordinate of Canvas.

I will put Buttons and labels in the frame so I chose not to use listbox.

Now, how do I make the scrollbar on the frame in such that if the label in the frame exceeds more than 5 (Each label are put in vertical way), then ScrollBar will appear?

Here is the sample Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.namelist = ["Mark","Anna","Jason","Lenna","Leo","Zucharich","Robinson","AReallyLongNameThatMightExist"]
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=1200,height=700)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
    def Friends(self):        
        controlframe = Frame(self.canvas)
        controlframe.place(x=600,y=300)
        #Frame for showing names of friends
        for x in self.namelist:
            frame = Frame(controlframe)
            frame.pack()
            Name = Label(frame,text="%s "%x).pack(side=LEFT)
            chatButton = Button(frame,text="Chat").pack(side=LEFT)
            delButton = Button(frame,text="Delete").pack(side=LEFT)
            setcloseButton = Button(frame,text="Set Close").pack(side=LEFT)
            setgroupButton = Button(frame,text="Set Group").pack(side=LEFT)
        mainloop()

GUI = GUI()
GUI.Friends()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not scroll the `Frame` but you can scroll the canvas. Be sure to set the scroll area of the canvas to the frame area. Then you can add a scrollbar with `pack()` and hide it with `pack_forget()`.

Maybe if you bind to the "configure" event of the frame you get to know when the size changes.

Comment: Maybe I can create a canvas then put the frame on that canvas.

Do you know how to put `limit` on the canvas in such that it only shows certain number of labels then if it exceeds, scrollbar will appear?